# WPF Frame - Size to content

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I've been having difficulty getting the WPF Frame control to resize to it's contents height (HTML).

(edit) the HTML content is 500px, I was expecting the first row to take this height, but the Frame is being clipped to 150px.

I've tried quite a few alterations on this theme:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
            Source="..\My Web Sites\test.html" />

    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Width="160" Height="50"                 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Book Todays Events" />

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Width="160" Height="50"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Content="Select Date" />
        <Border Width="350"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="Calendar" />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've tried swapping out the Frame for a ContentControl with 500px of content which worked fine, so I'm not sure what the problem is...

The HTML is a static height, and won't change at runtime, however the client will be able to alter it so I don't wan't to define a static height or hack into the HTML to find a height.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect the height to adjust when the size is auto?  Auto means it will adjust to the size of the content.  If the HTML is a static height then the row will be that static height.  Is that the behavior you are getting?  If you want each row to get half the screen height then use *.

Comment: that is the behaviour I was expecting too, but the Frame is being clipped to 150px with a scrollbar.

Comment: That is strange.  You don't even have a scrollbar in the XAML.